# Null String or not Null String?

Tags: java, null

I'm trying to get a string value from external file with this method:

```
File file = new File(name);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = br.readLine();
    br.close();
```

And I have some lines that are equal to "null". But if I compare them to null or "null", or even to "", I get FALSE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you compare them? That's the relevant code. (Also, what is in the line, `"null"`, `null`, empty string, or you really are getting the java `null` value?

Comment: Don't you need a loop to traverse through all the lines present in file. Right now it should be returining just first line and ending.

Comment: equal to ``null`` or String `"null"` ?

Comment: How some the lines can be `null`? It may be `empty` instead.

Comment: I don't know what I am getting from file. There is actually string "null" value, but if i compare it to string, it also returns false

Comment: And, I have 4-dimensional array, where the data from file is, maybe it's happening because of it?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: A line received from `readLine` can be `null` if at end of file; also, a string can be null for unrelated reasons, if we are not shown the exact code being run (happens quite often).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check the null or not then you can check like this way:

```
String a;
if(a!=null) {}
```

Or, if you want to compare two string are equivalent or no, then you can give condition like:

```
 String a="hello";
 if(a.equals("hello")) {}
```

If you get null then you must check if the result is null or not. You can do it like this:

```
if(result!=null && !result.equals("")) {


}
```

If the result is null then next condition will not check and your issue will solve.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to compare with `equals` method. in equal method if the parameter is null then it will return false. Use `==` operator instead.